# Gson parsing Arraylist<Myclass> into sharedpreferences, may it cause too much work on main thread?

Tags: android, arraylist, gson, sharedpreferences, logcat

in order to save and retreive my object Arraylist, and populate it into a (ListviewLike)recyclerview, i save it into Gson string, but if you suppose that the array size is like 500+ objects (object contains : title, description(50-1000+chars), thumb url,picture url...) when i load it from on create method, then put it into my recycler adapter, is that the main reason why i have those logcats logs :

`W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.937ms`

and

`Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26069(1300KB) AllocSpace objects, 19(886KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 84MB/86MB, paused 6.933ms total 82.250ms`

when i do an initial search, Objects are added one by one with asyncTask method, and i dont have neither supsending neither background sticky... logs. but when i need to retreive my Gson array from shared preferences, i dont have this kind of problem ( in reality, i dont really feel that all thread being suspended, or background concurrent sweep GC, but those logs appears and i really wonder if theres a solution too avoid them)